# Set operations on std::set

Tags: c++, stl

Several set operations (union, intersection, symmetric difference) are available in the C++ algorithm header: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union for example.

However, the std::set class itself doesn't provide union, intersection, and symmetric difference as member functions. Is there a specific reason for this?

Comment: _" Is there a specific reason for this?"_ Because these operations are already available in a generalized form from `<algorithm>`?

Comment: member functions are the last choice when designing a class interface, since they have the strongest coupling.

Comment: It's the [open/closed principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

Comment: Thanks for these replies. I suppose I could always writes these wrappers myself, such as defining an addition operator for std::set to represent unions ...